# Usb device attached & working in cmd, but not in explorer

Tags: command-line, usb, windows-explorer, mp3-player

A mp3 player (Zen Nano, if that matters) attached to a computer. Till now worked just fine.

Windows upon attaching didn't give any message (no baloons, no nothing). I thought the thing has died. Then I downloaded NirSoft's USBDeview, and it showed that it's still there with a drive letter F:

The player's normally accessible through command prompt. I can do everything with it I normally do (copy files, delete files ...). If I start explorer from the command prompt (via "explorer .") it won't start. Nothing happens.
If I start explorer via start menu, it doesn't show the drive.

Any ideas ? All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this forum post](http://www.anythingbutipod.com/forum/showthread.php?t=732), it could be a slight mismatch of drive letters for Zen Plus in windows.

> I figured it out. What I had to do was connect my Zen and go into the disk management utility - right-click on My Computer and click Manage. The zen should appear as a drive. Right-click on it and select Change Drive letter and paths...
>
> Change the Drive letter to a free drive and click Ok. It should work immediately!

Also, you may consider updating your pc's USB drivers. Be sure to make a system restore point before (even though this would probably be done automatically)

Comment: Aparently the problem fixed itself this morning. Don't know what it was, or how it fixed itself. Note to myself: Gotta restart windows at least twice a month.